# Does R have a "predict.glmList" function?

Tags: r

There is a R function (via the nlme package) [lmList](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/lmList.html) that contains a list of lm objects with a common model, after partitioning data according to a grouping factor. This has a lot of the useful methods that models typically have, such as predict. Is there an equivalent feature for glm?

I do see [glmlist](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vcdExtra/docs/coef.glmlist), but unlike lmlist it seems more to be a fancy container, with none of methods such as predict.

I.e. is there the equivalent of the following code for glm?

```
library(nlme)
fit <- lmList(disp ~ hp | vs, mtcars)
predict(fit,mtcars)
```

Comment: Can't you just `lapply` over the list? What exactly are you trying to do (never mind if the function already exists)? You should provide some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the code you are currently running. Clearly describe the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `lmList` in the `lme4` package can also handle GLM fits.  It probably hasn't been extensively tested for this use case, so be careful/report any problems you find to https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/ ...

e.g.

```
library(lme4)
fit <- lmList(round(disp) ~ hp | vs, family=poisson, mtcars)
predict(fit,mtcars)
```

gives the predicted values on the linear predictor scale.  Confusingly, `predict(fit)` gives the fitted values on the response scale, i.e.

```
all.equal(c(predict(fit)),c(exp(predict(fit,mtcars))))
```

is `TRUE` (in this case, and whenever the model uses a log link). `predict(fit,mtcars,type="response")` **silently** ignores the `type` specification ...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. There were some problems that I was able to get around, but I'm going to report those.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the documentation of `vcdExtra`, there does not seem to be one:

> glmlist creates a glmlist object containing a list of fitted glm objects with their names. [...]
>
> The intention is to provide object classes to facilitate model comparison, extraction, summary and
>   plotting of model components, etc., perhaps using lapply or similar.

However, you can do just that and define your own predict method based on `lapply`:

```
library(vcdExtra)

# simulate data
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- as.numeric(rnorm(100)>0)

fit <-  glm(y~x, family=binomial(link=logit))
gl <- glmlist(fit,fit)

# define method
predict.glmlist <- function(object, ...){

  expr <- substitute(predict.glm(obj,...))
  lapply(object, function(obj) eval(expr))

}

# use method
predict(gl)
predict(gl, type="response")
```